# R - function simplification and optimization

Tags: r, function, optimization

What the function does is finds the `primes` in `list1` and converts them to their equivalent `a` (i.e. 2 would be `a2` which is 1,1). Then it takes the `!NULL` in `list2` and searches if it is present in the converted `list1` (converted to a list of two of 1,2,3, or 4). Finally it returns a logical list of true and false which will be used later on. Even tough it works it looks really inefficient and long. Looking for any suggestions to improve this.

Test data:

```
list1<-c(11,2,29,5,17)
offspring<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(list1), nrow=1, byrow=T))

list2<-c(0,11)
parent<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(list2), nrow=1, byrow=T))
```

Prerequisites:

```
primes <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29)

a2 <- c(1,1)
a3 <- c(1,2)
a5 <- c(2,2)
a7 <- c(1,3)
a11 <- c(1,4)
a13 <- c(2,3)
a17 <- c(2,4)
a19 <- c(3,3)
a23 <- c(3,4)
a29 <- c(4,4)
```

The missing function:

```
missing <- function(offspring, parent){

  ofls <- lapply(1:ncol(offspring),FUN = function(i){get(paste0("a", offspring[i]))})
  pals <- lapply(1:length(parent[parent>0]),FUN = function(i){get(paste0("a", parent[parent>0]))})
  ofls<-data.frame(ofls)
  pals<-data.frame(pals)
  set1<- matrix(,nrow=10,ncol=1)
  set2<- matrix(,nrow=10,ncol=1)
  for(z in 1:5){
    set1[z,]<-match(ofls[1,z],pals[1,], nomatch=0)
    set1[z+5,]<-match(ofls[2,z],pals[1,], nomatch=0)
    set2[z,]<-match(ofls[1,z],pals[2,], nomatch=0)
    set2[z+5,]<-match(ofls[2,z],pals[2,], nomatch=0)

  }

  return((set1+set2)[c(1,2,3,4,5)]+(set1+set2)[c(6,7,8,9,10)]==0)


}

missing(offspring,parent)
```

Result:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

EDIT:
I corrected the mistake I found, in doing so the script go simplified a lot.

EDIT 2:
I am still getting an error in RStudio after running the function and then trying to `view()` the two data.frames:

```
Error in View : argument "title" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: I have tried understanding the code but its not making any sense. Can you explain what is the point of those ax variables and what is the goal of the "missing" function

Comment: These are alleles. 0 is a missing allele.`parents(0 AA) offspring(TT CT AA CC AT)`. The point of the function is to find mendelian errors even though one of the parents alleles is missing. So, in the above case an A has to be in all offsprings. I tried to do this by splitting up the alleles into 1,2,3,4 hence the ax variables.

Comment: I think I have a mistake somewhere in there (trying to find it now)

Comment: Questions about improving _working_ code are generally better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, basically anytime you are forced to use `get` in that fashion is a sign that you should have put `a2`, `a3`, etc in a list.

Comment: I see an Edit at the Bottom saying that you corrected a mistake,  does the error still occur???

Comment: @joran, this code doesn't function the way it is supposed to there is an error,  it is not a good fit for CodeReview until it is fixed

Comment: Reworded it a bit, yes still getting the error